# Leo Gecko Too Cold During the Winter?

Tags: reptiles, leopard-geckos, temperature

Over the summer I purchased a leopard gecko and have managed to keep her cage within the recommended warmth range, though recently I've noticed her cage becomes a little colder due to the winter season, specifically at night. The thermometer lists her cage to average 70 degrees Fahrenheit during the night. I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations on ways to heat her cage other than the heating pad I have for her currently. So far she doesn't seem too bothered by the slight coolness of her cage, but I would like to fix this problem before it becomes something bigger.